# How to pass soapui parameter in sql query with excel file?

Tags: soapui

in soapui i have a datasource with excel file containing sql query.
i have a jdbc step which connects to my db.
If i use the sql query with the excel file it works fine.
for exemple:

```
select name from person;
```

What i want to do is to pass soapui parameters in sql query like this:

```
select ${#Project#name} from person;
```

When i execute the test, the sql query in excel file is not able to retrieve the soapui parameter

```
${#Project#name}
```

Any help please.
Thank you

Comment: Are you executing the SQL in a Groovy script test step ?

Comment: No i'm executing the sql query with jdbc step, the sql query is in excel file.

Comment: I think it's not possible what i'm trying to do. Maybe i should pass the soapui parameter to excel with datasink step and then try to get the parameter in excel between cells. i tried this and it's not working for me.

Comment: I'd use Groovy. In fact I have used Groovy for this.

Comment: As @ou_rypered suggests, use a Groovy script.  I use JDBC a lot with SoapUI and barely use the ODBC test step.